# Rocky Release using Ubuntu 18.04 with netplan

Tags: networking, 18.04, openstack, netplan

I am currently using Newton with ubuntu 16.04 and would like to migrate to Rocky over Ubuntu 18.04. But I discovered that Ubuntu 18.04 is using netplan instead of ifupdown to manage the network ressources. I realize that it is more an Openstack question but since Openstack required quite a bit of complexity in the networking I think posting the question here is more adequate.

I have the following interfaces file for ubuntu 16.04 and looking on documentation on how to convert that setup to netplan ?

Any body can help ? Thanks

Here is my current ifupdown configuration

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet manual

auto eno3
iface eno3 inet manual
    mtu 9000

auto eno4
iface eno4 inet manual

# Container/Host management bridge
auto br-mgmt
iface br-mgmt inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports eno2
    address 10.10.10.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0

# OpenStack Networking VXLAN (tunnel/overlay) bridge
auto br-vxlan
iface br-vxlan inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports eno3
    address 10.10.11.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    mtu 9000

# OpenStack Networking VLAN bridge
auto br-vlan
iface br-vlan inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports eno1
    address x.x.14.50
    netmask 255.255.240.0
    network x.x.0.0
    broadcast x.x.15.255
    gateway x.x.10.15
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers x.x.0.254 x.x.0.250
    dns-search domlinast.loc
    pre-up ip link add br-vlan-veth type veth peer name eth12 || true
    pre-up ip link set br-vlan-veth up
    pre-up ip link set eth12 up
    post-down ip link del br-vlan-veth || true
    bridge_ports eno1 br-vlan-veth

# Storage bridge
auto br-storage
iface br-storage inet static
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_ports eno4
    address 10.10.12.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample netplan config I am using:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
# When using bridging move this block to the bridge definition or it wont work... dont really kno why
#      addresses: [192.168.2.22/24]
#      gateway4: 192.168.2.1
#      nameservers:
#              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses: [192.168.2.22/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.2.1
      nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      parameters:
              stp: false
              forward-delay: 0
      interfaces: [eno1]
```

Once you have the file set-up you need to apply it:

```
# netplan apply
```